# Oracle Dynamic query to delete all object of schema except exclude two tables and their relative object like trigger function, index or procedure

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql

I want to delete all the objects related to schema, this was achievable by below query i was using before :-

```
 USER_SCHM_NAME=Employee
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<EOF >>$ORA_ERR
set feedback off
set echo off
set trimspool on
set termout off
set serveroutput on size 100000 format wrapped
set lines 500
set pages 0
spool /tmp/drop_obj_$ORACLE_SID_$DATE2.sql
select 'drop table ${USER_SCHM_NAME}.'||table_name||' cascade constraints;' from dba_tables where owner='${USER_SCHM_NAME}' order by table_name;
select 'drop '||object_type||' ${USER_SCHM_NAME}.'||object_name||';' from dba_objects where owner='${USER_SCHM_NAME}' order by object_type;
select 'drop type ${USER_SCHM_NAME}.'||object_name||';' from dba_objects where owner='${USER_SCHM_NAME}' and object_type='TYPE';
select 'drop operator ${USER_SCHM_NAME}.CONVERTTYPES;' from dual;
select 'purge dba_recyclebin;' from dual;
spool off
spool /tmp/op_drop_obj_$ORACLE_SID_$DATE2.log
@/tmp/drop_obj_$ORACLE_SID_$DATE2.sql
spool off
EOF
```

Now i want to delete all object exclude two tables and objects related to that tables like indexes,trigger,procedure, function, packages..

I use below query to exclude those two tables :-

```
select 'drop table ${USER_SCHM_NAME}.'||table_name||' cascade constraints;' from dba_tables where owner='${USER_SCHM_NAME}' and table_name not in ('EMPLOYEE_DETAIL', 'EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_DETAILS') order by table_name;
```

But how can i exclude objects related to those two table, kindly help me with that

Comment: Are these huge tables with heavy data? If not, is it possible to copy the required tables and dependent objects to a new schema, drop all objects in current schema and copy the retained objects back to the current schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to drop individual `object_types` separately ( indexes,trigger,procedure, function, packages) rather than using a single drop statement like this.

```
drop  '||object_type||' ${USER_SCHM_NAME}.'||object_name||';'
```

You may also exclude the constraints,indexes,triggers,procedure, function, packages though using something like this instead of plainly using above statement.

The `user_source` exclusion should take care of triggers, packages, procedure, functions

```
SELECT 'drop ' || object_type || ' ${USER_SCHM_NAME}.' || object_name || ';'
FROM dba_objects d
WHERE OWNER = '${USER_SCHM_NAME}'
AND object_name not in ('EMPLOYEE_DETAIL', 'EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_DETAILS')
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM (
            SELECT constraint_name AS object_name
            FROM dba_constraints
            WHERE table_name in('EMPLOYEE_DETAIL', 'EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_DETAILS')
                AND OWNER = '${USER_SCHM_NAME}'
               UNION ALL
            SELECT index_name AS object_name
            FROM dba_indexes
            WHERE table_name IN (
                    'EMPLOYEE_DETAIL'
                    ,'EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_DETAILS'
                    )
                AND OWNER = '${USER_SCHM_NAME}'
                 UNION ALL
            SELECT NAME AS object_name
            FROM dba_source
            WHERE (
                    upper(TEXT) LIKE '%EMPLOYEE_DETAIL%'
                    OR upper(TEXT) LIKE '%EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_DETAILS%'
                    )
                AND OWNER = '${USER_SCHM_NAME}'
            ) c
        WHERE c.object_name = d.object_name
        );
```